# Binding a single value within a for comprehension

Tags: scala, haskell, for-comprehension

The [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/) tutorial has an example of [using a `let` binder in a list comprehension](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions#let-it-be):

```
calcBmis xs = [bmi | (w, h) <- xs, let bmi = w / h ^ 2, bmi >= 25.0]
```

The function takes a list of height/weight pairs, and returns a list of the corresponding body-mass indices that exceed some limit, eg:

```
ghci> calcBmis [(70, 1.85), (50, 2.00), (130, 1.62)]
[49.53513183965858]
```

What's interesting to me here is that the value `bmi` that is bound within the comprehension can be used both in a guard and in the resulting expression. The only way I know how to do something similar in Scala is to write:

```
def calcBmis(xs : Seq[(Double,Double)]) =
  for((w,h) <- xs ; bmi <- Some(w / (h*h)) if bmi >= 25.0) yield bmi
```

Having to wrap my value in a `Some` here feels wrong. Anyone knows of a better way?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, there is such syntax.

```
def calcBmis(xs : Seq[(Double,Double)]) =
  for((w,h) <- xs ; bmi = w / (h*h); if bmi >= 25.0) yield bmi
```

One-liner alternative (but not comprehension):

```
calcBmis.map(wh => wh._1/(wh._2*wh._2)).filter(_>=25.0)
```

Comment: OK, I was missing the semi-column :) To my defense, that key is hardly ever used on my keyboard when I write Scala code.

Answer (score 1):

I've just copied om-nom-nom's answer to show how you can lay it out using curly braces without the semicolons; it's a bit clearer this way

```
def calcBmis(xs : Seq[(Double,Double)]) = for { (w,h) <- xs 
                                                bmi = w / (h*h)
                                                if bmi >= 25.0 } yield bmi
```

and instead of using tuples, I'd use a `case` expression (again, requires curly braces)

```
xs map {case (w, h) => w / (h * h)} filter {_ >= 25.0}
```